# Avoiding price fluctuations when transfering money

Tags: exchange-rate, wire-transfers

I would like to buy bitcoins in one currency and withdraw them in another at the exact price I bought them at - same day (I want to avoid all risk of fluctuating prices). Is there somewhere that offers this service?

Thanks

Comment: I don't follow. If it's "another" currency, how can it be the "exact price"? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167586). Why don't you tell us what actual problem you have and let us suggest ways to solve it? (Rather than asking us to help you implement a solution without telling us what it is supposed to solve.)